# Nginx + PHP index.php not found 404

Tags: nginx, php, http-status-code-404, indexing

I'm running debian 9 with nginx 12 and php7.1

I've set evrrything up.
Nginx does not give me anything in error log, all the PHP scripts are working 100% fine. Nginx indexes index.html as index but DOES NOT find index.php and returns 404, even though I have it set in the nginx config.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri /index.html index.php;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #


    location ~ \.php$ {

            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}}
```

Answer (score 0):

All good, figured it out :)
This was the mistake I had in my cfg:

```
 location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri /index.html index.php;
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly the same config you said was not working above.